# finding minimum number in each matrix row

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to write a code to find a minimum number from the 'distance' matrix, excluding zeroes from the matrix.

```
distance=[0    0.44    0.40    0.63    0.89
0.44    0       0.44    0.72    1.00
0.40    0.44    0       0.28    0.56
0.63    0.72    0.28    0       0.28
0.89    1.00    0.56    0.28    0]

for  i=1:Nodes
    for  j=1:Nodes
        if (distance(i,j)~=0)

        [mini(i,:)]=[min(distance(i,:))];
        end
    end
end
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What results does the code that you have give you?

Comment: it gives me an array of zeros :(

Comment: use `d`instead of `distance`.

Comment: that ain't the issue, sir!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer is:

```
d = distance;
d(~d) = inf;
mini = min(d);
```

First you get rid of the zero entries, then you let Matlab calculate the minimum per row.

You should always try to avoid loops in Matlab.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try and avoid loops in my further programs!

Comment: Very nice, this definately answers the question as it was asked. However @happyme as it is a distance matrix, you usually may be more interested in this instead: `d(logical(eye(size(d)))) = Inf` This enables you to calculate the minimum distance to 'other' points. (Same result for your example matrix)

Answer (score 0):

Though I would recommend a vectorized solution as @ypnos offered, here is one way to make your loop work.

```
mini = inf(1,Nodes)
for  i=1:Nodes
    for  j=1:Nodes
        if (distance(i,j)~=0) %Consider using if i~=j if you want the distance to 'other' points
            mini(j)=min(distance(i,j),mini(j));
        end
    end
end
```